What is the best practice for handling auth sessions in a CLI application?
I've looked up similar questions on SO and Reddit, but none of them seem to have an accepted answer, which is why I'm hoping to get some insight here.
I'm building a Node + Express application that will serve as a remote API accessible by HTTP. There will be two different client implementations - a web app and a CLI tool. I have worked enough with web apps to know that cookies are the standard for handling somewhat long-lived sessions (30 days).
I have never built a CLI tool before, and I'm curious to know what the industry standard for keeping track of sessions is. I have thought about using a JSON file stored in the user's HOME directory, kind of like how GCP service account keys work, but instead of storing the actual credentials it would store something that will let the CLI tool check if the session is valid or not.
Again, this is the first time I'm doing this for a CLI tool, so feedback, criticism and reading resources (if any) will be greatly appreciated!
